# Common business logic in android MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, android-development, data-binding

**Requirement**

I am currently working on an android application that uses MVVM, live data and databinding. I have a use-case where I need to show a Comment button in multiple screens in my android app.

The business logic is simple, when the user clicks on the button I need to check if the user is logged-in to the app or not.
If yes, I take the user to a screen where he would be able to view all comments. If not, then I need to show a login screen; and after login I show the comment's screen. I'd like to know if there is an efficient way to handle this so that I dont need to duplicate my code across multiple screens and view models.

**Solution 1**

One way I thought of doing this is to have the login button in a fragment which I include in all screens required. The fragment would have a view-model and the live data observer.
Whenever the user clicks on the button, I check in the view model if the user is logged in or not. If yes I set the live data to have value LOGGED_IN else I set NOT_LOGGED_IN. When I receive the callback in my fragment I re-direct him the appropriate screen.

**Problem with Solution 1**

One problem I can see with the above approach is if the UI of the comment button changes I would need to write additional code in the fragment to handle that.

**Solution 2**

Pass the view model for the comment button as constructor to the view model of the activity

Although this would work fine, I haven't seen anyone do this. Are there any problems with approach 2?

**Question**

Which of the above two methods would be better? Are there any other solution that you guys could help me with?